# Jenkins execution with node and dwupload module return Error: ca key too small

Tags: node.js, jenkins, salesforce, node-modules

We're using `Jenkins (2.235.2)` with BlueOcean in docker-compose with a slave from jenkinsci/jnlp-slave:latest. 
So, when I need to use `node(10.15.3)` and `dwupload(3.8.2)` to delivery a cartridge in Salesforce sandbox with a two factory authentication we are getting the following error:

```sh
# command
dwupload --hostname cert.staging.(...).demandware.net --username **** --password **** --cartridge cartridges/lib_productlist --code-version hav_12 --p12 **** --passphrase ****
```

```sh
# error logs
{ 'file-upload': false, 'cartridge-upload': false, 'directory-create': false, 'file-delete': false } [15:28:53] Error: ca key too small
```

Could you help me, please.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem in a Jenkins pipeline. Did you have any luck solving it?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL is the culprit in this case, since not-so-newer installations requests longer key lengths, so there are two ways to solve this:

- The "The old quick and dirty way": Just lower it:

```sh
sudo cp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf{,.backup}
sudo sed -i 's/SECLEVEL=2/SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

And you're good to go. If you're running Jenkins using Docker images, you're gonna have to update them. The problem with that approach is that it is system-wide.

- You can change it just for `dwupload` by creating an alternate OpenSSL configuration file in your Jenkins pipeline. Something like this:

```
sh "sed 's/SECLEVEL=2/SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf > openssl_custom.cnf"
sh "OPENSSL_CONF=openssl_custom.cnf dwupload --hostname ${hostname} --username ${username} ..."
sh "rm -rf openssl_custom.cnf"
```

Abraços!